# AS2: Stopping Array Loop when Timer hits 0

Tags: flash, timer, actionscript-2, goto

I'm a newbie here!  Hi, you can call me Bri!  I need some help working with Actionscript-2 coding in a game I'm making with 'Macromedia Flash Professional 8.' (I know it's a bit dated; I'm upgrading soon)!

It's a catching game:  **I have eggs falling from the sky.  When my catcher catches an egg, the score goes up by one point.**  My hit test works, and I have 2 types of eggs falling: Blue and Pink. (They're both worth 1 point when caught).

I just added a timer to my game.  *What I need to happen is: When **the timer hits zero**, the game goes to the "gameover" screen so that the players can restart the game. 
The problem is, when the timer hits zero, the game goes to the "gameover" screen, but **the eggs keep falling** over the "gameover" screen.*

***I need them to stop falling.***

I've tried putting the **stop();** code on the first and last frame of the "gameon" label in my timeline.  I've placed **stop();** at the top and bottom of the code on the first and last frame, as well as on the new frame (sans the rest of the code) where I want the playerhead to move.  I've also gone into the code itself and tried to **"pop," "shift,"** and **"splice"** my array.  I've also tried the basic **.removeMovieClip** function to remove each egg itself (*BlueEgg, PinkEgg, newClip, this* <=  I've tried all of these to call back my function, you'll see how each has been referenced in my code).

I think my problem is...1) I don't know WHERE, in the code, to place the function for the array of eggs to stop falling.  (Should the code for the 'timer' be at the top, or should it come right after the code for the 'falling eggs'?  If after, where within the 'timer' code can I call the function to stop the eggs' "falling" action?  Should that action even be within the 'timer' code, or should it sit on another line by itself)?  and 2) I don't know HOW to successfully make the eggs just **STOP** falling (do I pop, shift, splice, clear, remove, etc.?  And how do I code whatever the function is)?

Here is my current code:

```
    newClip = _root.attachMovie('Uni', 'Uni', -1);
Uni._y = Stage.height-315;
Uni._x = Stage.width-225;
function moveUni() {
    if (Uni._x<30) {
        Uni._x = 30;
    }
    if (Uni._x>520) {
        Uni._x = 520;
    }
    if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
        dx = 15;
        Uni._xscale = -100;
    } else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
        dx = -15;
        Uni._xscale = 100;
    } else {
        dx = 0;
    }
    Uni._x += dx;
    if (Uni._x<30) {
        Uni._x = 30;
    }
    if (Uni._x>520) {
        Uni._x = 520;
    }
}
this.onEnterFrame = function() {
    moveUni();
};
//
depth = 0;
var score = 0;
var allEggs = new Array();
function makeNewClip() {
    clearInterval(ranID);
    ran = (Math.random()*4000)+1000;
    ranID = setInterval(makeNewClip, ran);
    ran = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);
    if (ran == 1) {
        newClip = _root.attachMovie('BlueEgg', 'BlueEgg'+depth, depth++);
    } else {
        newClip = _root.attachMovie('PinkEgg', 'PinkEgg'+depth, depth++);
    }
    allEggs.push(newClip);
    trace("allEggs");
    newClip._x = Math.random()*Stage.width;
    newClip._y = -50;
    newClip.speed = 13;
    newClip._xscale = newClip._yscale=50;
    newClip.onEnterFrame = function() {
        this._y += this.speed;
        if (Math.abs(Uni._x-this._x)<=25) {
            if (Math.abs(Uni._y-this._y)<=25) {
                trace('hit');
                this.removeMovieClip();
                score++;
                score_txt.text = score;
            }
        }
    };
}

//

var intID;
var endTime = getTimer()+(5*1000);
makeTime();
function updateTimer() {
    var t = endTime-getTimer();
    if (t>0) {
        makeTime();
        showTime(t);
    } else {
        stopTimer();
        showTime(0);


    }
}
function makeTime() {
    clearInterval(intID);
    intID = setInterval(updateTimer, 100);
    gotoAndStop(20);
}

function showTime(t) {
    timer_txt.text = (t/1000) >> 0;

    }

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(intID);

}

//  
makeNewClip();
//
makeNewClip();
newClip = _root.attachMovie('TallGrassOverlay', 'TallGrassOverlay', 1);
TallGrassOverlay._y = Stage.height-230;
TallGrassOverlay._x = Stage.width-585;
```

The TallGrasssOverlay doesn't do anything but serve as an extra graphic to help make the game pop to the player's eye.  But it's graphic that needs to lay on top of the moving catcher, Uni.

Also, it should be noted that I haven't begun coding the button that will actually restart the game yet.

Thanks so much in advance!

-Bri

Comment: Make sure to do a clearInterval(ranID); then loop through the allEggs array, do a removeMovieClip() on all of its items and finally clear the array.

Comment: Hi Will!  Thank you so, so SO much for your help!!  :D  I really appreciate it!!  Because of your advice I was able to finish up my game and publish earlier this evening!  :-)  Thanks again!